# How to sync index between view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I'd like to implement something like [PageMenu](https://github.com/HighBay/PageMenu). Currently, I have a root view controller with 2 containers inside, named **headerViewController** and **containerViewController**.
[image]
I've set everything up but I have no idea how to synchronize the behaviour between these two view controllers.

**- How can I send my index from UICollectionViewController to UIPageViewController?**

**- How can I change the index in UICollectionViewController when UIPageViewController did Scroll?**

**rootViewController**

```
var headerViewController: PageMenuViewController?
var containerViewController: PageViewController?

override func awakeFromNib() {
    pages = [Pages(name: "Page1", selected: true, url: photo1), Pages(name: "Page2", url: video1)]
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

// MARK: Navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "rootViewSegue" {
        containerViewController = segue.destination as? PageViewController
        containerViewController!.controllerArray = pages
    } else if segue.identifier == "headerViewSegue" {
        headerViewController = segue.destination as? PageMenuViewController
        headerViewController!.dataArray = pages
    }
}
```

**containerViewController(UIPageViewController)**

```
func jumpToPage(_ index: Int) {
    if index < orderedViewControllers.count {
        setViewControllers([orderedViewControllers[index]], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

**headerViewController (UICollectionViewController)**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Sync index with containerViewController
    // How to use jumpToPage ??
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the delegation pattern, `rootViewController` will implement the protocols `containerViewControllerDelegate` and `headerViewControllerDelegate` so you can pass the data through these delegates.

Let me know if you need an example.

Comment: Yes an example would be good for others that may want a solution to this

Answer (score 0):

According to @SaintThread's answer. The [protocol/delegate](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/04/08/how-delegation-works-a-swift-developer-guide/) works for me.

**RootViewController**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, PageMenuDelegate, PageViewDelegate {

// MARK: Data Source
let photo1 = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "pageView", withExtension: ".png")!
let video1 = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "ElephantSeals", withExtension: ".mov")!
var pages = [Pages]()

var headerViewController: PageMenuViewController?
var containerViewController: PageViewController?

var currentIndex = 0

override func awakeFromNib() {
    pages = [Pages(name: "Page1", selected: true, url: photo1), Pages(name: "Page2", url: video1)]
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    headerViewController?.delegate = self
    containerViewController?.containerDelegate = self
}

// MARK: Navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "rootViewSegue" {
        containerViewController = segue.destination as? PageViewController
        containerViewController!.controllerArray = pages
    } else if segue.identifier == "headerViewSegue" {
        headerViewController = segue.destination as? PageMenuViewController
        headerViewController!.dataArray = pages
    }
}

// Delegate in CollectionViewController
func selectItem(at index: Int) {
    containerViewController?.pageIndex = index
    currentIndex = index
}

// Delegate in UIPageViewController
func scrollTo(_ index: Int) {
    headerViewController?.setSelectedItem(at: IndexPath(row: index, section: 0))
    currentIndex = index
}

}
```

**CollectionViewController**

```
protocol PageMenuDelegate {
    func selectItem(at index: Int)
}

class PageMenuViewController: UIViewController {
    var delegate: PageMenuDelegate?
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        setSelectedItem(at: indexPath)
        delegate?.selectItem(at: indexPath.row) // HERE
    }

    func setSelectedItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) {
        for i in 0..<dataArray.count {
            dataArray[i].selected = false
        }
        dataArray[indexPath.row].selected = true
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

**PageViewController**

```
protocol PageViewDelegate {
    func scrollTo(_ index: Int)
}

class PageViewController: UIPageViewController {
    var containerDelegate: PageViewDelegate? // "delegate" collides with pageview delegate

    var pageIndex: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            jumpToPage(pageIndex)
            containerDelegate?.scrollTo(pageIndex) //HERE
        }
    }

    func jumpToPage(_ index: Int) {
        if index < orderedViewControllers.count {
            setViewControllers([orderedViewControllers[index]], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}

extension PageViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        ... pageIndex = index //HERE
    }
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        ... pageIndex = index //HERE

    }
}
```